# Efficient Multithreaded .parquet Cell Encoding Detection in Python

Tags: python, database, multithreading, encoding, multiprocessing

the following script only uses 7-15% of my ryzen 7 4800H. Why is that? How can i make it use all my CPU-Power, so it doesn't take forever to finish?

```py
# Importing necessary libraries
import os
import pandas as pd
import cchardet as chardet
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Path to the folder
folder_path = '/home/master/Documents/smb/'
read_path = '/home/master/Documents/smb/read/'

def process_cell(args):
    # Processing each cell's text
    row, column, filename = args
    try:
        # Detecting encoding using cchardet
        result = chardet.detect(row[column])
        encoding = result['encoding']

        if encoding is not None:
            # Attempting to decode the text
            text = row[column].decode(encoding)

            # Printing text and its encoding if successful
            print(f"Text: {text}, Encoding: {encoding}")

            # Saving text and encoding in a JSON file
            i = 0
            while os.path.exists(f"{read_path}read-db{i}.json"):
                i += 1
            with open(f"{read_path}read-db{i}.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(text, f, indent=2)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # Skipping the cell if decoding is not successful
        pass
    except LookupError:
        # Skipping the cell if encoding is unknown
        pass

def main():
    # Getting list of filenames in the folder
    filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(folder_path) if filename.endswith('.parquet')]
    
    # Creating a process pool with available CPU cores
    with Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
        for filename in filenames:
            # Creating full path to the file
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            
            # Reading the file using pandas
            df = pd.read_parquet(file_path)
            
            # Collecting arguments for processes in the pool
            args_list = [(row, column, filename) for _, row in df.iterrows() for column in df.columns]
            
            # Processing cells using a process from the pool
            pool.map(process_cell, args_list)
        
        # Waiting for all processes to finish
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Tried:
Researching: Other Libs, known issues, different multithread implementations i found on github
ChatGPT & Phind.com

Expected:
Having a working script (i mean it workes, it's just slow af)

What it actually resulted in?:
Only using 7-15% of my r7 4800H

SRY for my bad english btw

Comment: Could it be that your application has a lot of reading from disk?

Comment: @Booboo yeah, the dataset it's reading and decoding is around 180gb

Comment: So when a process is waiting for an I/O request to complete, the CPU will be idle.

Comment: i know, but the cpu isn't over 15% at any time

Comment: That's because 85% of the time you are waiting for an I/O request, which uses no CPU, to complete. You could always insert a `for _ in range(10_000_000): pass` loop guaranteed to get your CPU usage up causing your program to take more time to complete while accomplishing nothing towards your ultimate goal.

Comment: shit, thank you for explaining tho

Comment: You seem disappointed. It appears that the nature of your processing is that you are spending 15% of the time executing Python code and 85% of the time waiting for an I/O request to complete before you can continue spinning more CPU cycles. That's just the nature of your code. If you don't have a solid state drive, you could get one which would reduce the I/O wait time percentage and total running time. If I/O could be done instantaneously your CPU utilization will always be 100% as long as some process is running on every core.